# Python Requests hanging multiprocessing pool on Gateway errors (502, 504)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

I have a script that uploads data to a third party API server in parallel using `requests.put()` and a multiprocessing Pool. The process runs the requests in batches of four to avoid hitting the API's max concurrent connection limit and rate limit. This process has built in error handling to catch failed POST requests using the `Response.rasie_for_status()` method and either retry the request or log the failure and send an alert email depending on the status code.

The code below is a sample from the function that uploads the data to the API.

```
import requests
import retry
from notifications import send_error_msg #local module

@retry(requests.HTTPError, delay=5, max_delay=60, backoff=2)
def upload_data(method, url, payload, headers):
    #method='PUT'
    response = requests.request(method=method, url=url, json=payload, headers=headers, timeout=120)
    response.close()
    #Check for additional failures
    try:
        logging.debug('Check for successful upload')
        response.raise_for_status()
        logging.debug('Check completed... Upload Successful')
    except:
        logging.debug('Check failed... Upload was not successful')
        if(response.status_code == 502):
            message = response.reason
        else:
            message = response.json()["Message"]
        #End if/else
        logging.debug('We made it past setting the message variable')
        #Check for rate limit/ raise error for retry
        if(response.status_code == 429):
            logging.warn(f'Rate limit hit\nRequest Error Message: {message}')
            response.raise_for_status()
        #End if
        logging.error(f'Upload Failed\nRequest Error Message: {message}\nURL: {url}\nRequest Payload: {payload}')
        send_error_msg(f"HTTPS {response.status_code} Error", 
        f"Upload Failed with HTTPS Status Code: {response.status_code}\n",
        f"Error: {message}\n\nURL: {url}Request Payload: {payload}")
        return 0
    logging.info('Data successfully uploaded to API')
```

The code below is an excerpt from the main function that establishes the pool and batches out the parallel uploads to the `processQuery()` function which calls the `upload_data()` function. The time it takes to upload the data is returned from `processQuery()` back to `main()` and is used to determine how long to wait before kicking off the next batch.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from sql_ops import sql_conn() #local module

def main():
    queries = #List of queries to run
    #Break queries into batches of 4
    batch_q = [queries[i: i+4] for i in range(0, len(queries), 4)]
    pool = Pool(4, maxtasksperchild=1)
    #Loop through and process queries
    for batch in batch_q:
        times = pool.map(func=processQuery, iterable=batch)

        #Determine how much time to wait before next batch
        time_to_wait = 30 - max(times) #Done to avoid rate limit
        #time_to_wait must be positive
        if(time_to_wait > 0):
            time.sleep(time_to_wait)
        #End if
    #End for loop
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    logging.info("Finished processing all queries. Exiting Program...")
#End main()

def processQuery(query):

    #Generate API Token
    token = authenticate() #Returns headers for the API request (defined earlier in the module)
    #Get sql connection 
    connect = sql_conn() #Returns pyodbc.connect()
    cursor = connect.cursor()

    data = get_data(cursor, query) #Function is defined elsewhere

   #Close SQL connections
    cursor.close()
    connect.close()

    logging.info(f"Uploading data")
    post_start = time.perf_counter()
    upload_data(method='PUT', url='https://api.url.here/path', payload=data, headers=token)
    post_end = time.perf_counter() - post_start #Calculate time it took to run upload

    logging.info(f"Completed Running query returning to main()")
    return post_end
#End processQuery()
```

Upon an HTTPS 502 or 504 error, the process completes through the log `logging.info(f"Completed running query returning to main()")` in `processQuery()` but hangs after and never returns to the main function to execute the next batch. All batches after are never run, and looking in Task Manager all 4 threads remain "open" indefeinalty until the main script is manually killed.

The request has a timeout set as well as the response being closed after making the request so nothing should be open. At this point I'm not sure what is causing the pool to hang, but it only occurs when an HTTPS 502 or 504 error occurs.

Because the 502 and 504 errors happen sporadically I have been not able to manually reproduce this issue. I have even used https://httpstat.us/502 to test against with no luck.
Note: This script runs in a cloud environment.

**Update -------------------------------------------------------------**

I added some more logging and try/except logic to my original code and pin pointed the "hang" at `return post_code` at the end of the `processQuery` function. I also did some more local testing and believe that the child process may be silently dying. I found similar behavior where the entire process hangs with no output or termination when running an `os.kill(getpid(), 9)` within the child process.
The code below is what I used to produce the similar behavior.

```
import requests
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
from os import getpid, kill
import logging

def make_request(num):
    if(num != 4 and num != 8 and num != 12):
        response = requests.put('https://httpstat.us/200', json={'somedata': 'There is some data'}, timeout=120)
    else:
        response = requests.put('https://httpstat.us/502?sleep=5000', json={'somedata': 'There is some data'}, timeout=120)
        print(response.history)
    #End if
    response.close()
    return response

def runRequest(num):
    print(f'Thread {getpid()}: Running request: {num}')

    response = make_request(num)

    try:
        print(f'Thread {getpid()}: Checking if requests succeded. Status Code: {response.status_code}')
        response.raise_for_status()
        print(f'Thread {getpid()}: It worked!!!')
    except:
        print(f'Thread {getpid()}: Nope, it did not work')
        print(response.reason)
        kill(getpid(), 9)
    #End try/except
    logging.info(f'Thread {getpid()}: The request completed successfully!')
#End runRequest

def runStuff(num):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    runRequest(num)
    end = time.perf_counter() - start

    print(f'Thread {getpid()}: Finished running request. It took {end}s')
    return end
#End runStuff


def main():
    lis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
    batch_q = [lis[i: i+4] for i in range(0, len(lis), 4)]

    pool = Pool(4, maxtasksperchild=1)
    for batch in batch_q:
        try:
            times = pool.map(func=runStuff, iterable=batch)
        except:
            print('Aww something happened')
        #End try except

        print(times)
        print('Batch completed...')
        time_to_wait = 10 - max(times)
        print(f'Time to wait is {time_to_wait}s')

        if(time_to_wait > 0):
            time.sleep(time_to_wait)
        #End if
    #End for loop
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
#End main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
#End main()
```